# MsgBox is showed to load form before the ComboBox click event ocurrs

Tags: combobox, vb6

I a newbie in VB6 . I have a comboBox control called "combo". I need to show the value of selected combo item when the click event ocurrs. Hovewer the MsgBox is showed to load the form

```
Private Sub combo_Click()

   label_1.Caption = combo.Text
   MsgBox combo.Text


End Sub

Private Sub combo_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
 KeyAscii = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim nombre1 As String
    Dim apellido1 As String
    nombre1 = nombre.Text
    apellido1 = apellido.Text
    resultado.Text = nombre1 + " " + apellido1
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
  combo.AddItem ("fernando")
  combo.AddItem ("juan")
  combo.AddItem ("pepep")
  combo.AddItem ("jose")
  combo.AddItem ("luis")
  combo.ListIndex = 0


End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you set `ListIndex` from `Form_Load`, naturally that causes a `Click` (which fires when the value is changed with the mouse or the `ListIndex`).

Comment: Thanks a lot GSerg. The problem is that i need the item "fernando" appears to load the form. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event occurs even if no click was made. It occurs in the Form Load when you put combo.ListIndex = 0. suppress this line and no msgbox will occurs at form load. But if you want to assign a default value at form load then you may use flag.

```
Private Ignore As Boolean
Private Sub combo_Click()
   Label_1.Caption = Combo.Text
   If Ignore Then
        Ignore = False
   Else
        MsgBox Combo.Text
   End If
End Sub
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim nombre1 As String
    Dim apellido1 As String
    nombre1 = nombre.Text
    apellido1 = apellido.Text
    resultado.Text = nombre1 + " " + apellido1
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Combo.AddItem ("fernando")
  Combo.AddItem ("juan")
  Combo.AddItem ("pepep")
  Combo.AddItem ("jose")
  Combo.AddItem ("luis")
  Ignore = True
  Combo.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```